# HTML meta viewport tag being ignored on Safari and Chrome on Apple Devices

Tags: html, ios, safari, responsive, viewport

I have a web page that has this html meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

It works fine while testing on my Windows machine applying responsive views in any browser. 
Also it works fine on any browser on Android devices. 
The issue happens when I try to open Safari or Chrome on my iPhone or Mac Book, the meta viewport tag values doesn't get respected and gets ignored.
The screen is not showing up to this scale or device width.

So, are there any specific configurations or content values that would make the iOS respect the meta viewport tag content and not ignore it?